# The quadratic fields are of the form $\Bbb Q(\sqrt d) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, algebraic-number-theory

We want to prove that the quadratic fields have form $\Bbb Q(\sqrt d) $, where $d\neq 0,1$  is a square free integer.

*Proof*. Let $F$ be a quadratic field. So we have $F=\Bbb Q(\alpha)$, for some $\alpha \in \Bbb C$. So, the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha \in \Bbb C$ is $\deg f_\alpha = 2$. So, this polynomial has the form
$$f_\alpha(X) =X^2+pX+q,$$
where $p, q\in \Bbb Q$. So, since $\alpha $ is a root, it must be
$$\alpha=-p/2\pm \sqrt D, $$
where $D = p^2 /4-q \in \Bbb Q$. Clearly $D $ is not $0$. Then,
$$F= \Bbb Q(\alpha) =\Bbb Q(-p/2 \pm \sqrt D) =\Bbb Q(\sqrt D). $$

Since $D\in \Bbb Q$, $D=a/b$, for some integers $a,b $ with $b≠0$. So, $b^2D=ab$.

In this point, in my notes it is written *"collecting all squares in $ab$ together, we can write $ab = c^
2d$, with $c, d \in \Bbb Z \backslash \{0\}$ and
d squarefree." *

I can not understand this step. It might be an easy one, but frankly I can't see it. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Every integer can be reduced to prime factorization. So, collect all maximum even powers of primes into some number $c^2$.

Example: $3^5 5^8 7^4 11^1 13^5 = (3^2 5^4 7^2 13^2)^2 (3 \cdot 11 \cdot 13)$

Now $D=\left(\dfrac c b\right)^2 d$

So $\sqrt{D}= \dfrac{c}{b}\sqrt{d}$ with $d$ a square free integer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, in the prime factorisation of $ab\in \Bbb Z$, we collect the maximum even powers of its prime factors. But how do we know that they exist?

Comment: We know they exist because $ab$ is an integer, so it has a prime factorization. Those prime factors will have finite powers. That is all part of the prime factorization theorem. And zero is an even number, so if all prime factors have at most a power of 1, then $c^2=1$

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to InterstellarProbe's prime-factorization approach:

For any integer $n\not=0$ (e.g., $n=ab$), let $c$ be the largest positive integer such that $c^2\mid n$.  (There must be such a largest $c$, since $1^2\mid n$ and $c^2\not\mid n$ if $c\gt|n|$.) Let $d=n/c^2$. If $d$ were not squarefree -- i.e., if $r^2\mid d$ with $r\gt1$ -- then we would have $(rc)^2\mid n$ with $rc\gt c$, which contradicts the defining property of $c$. We thus have $n=c^2d$ with $c,d\in\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}$ and $d$ squarefree.

Comment: Nice proof, thank you!